# iOS: default segue animation violated and destroy my other animation timing

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, uiview, segue

I use default segue between two View Controllers with default type Show. It has default slide animation and I perform it programmatically. On the second view controller I have an animation.
When I open second view controller for the first time, all animation is ok – animation of segue and animation related to 2nd view controller work fine as expected.

When I tap back button and open 2nd view controller again, there is no slide segue animation (no animation at all I mean), 2nd view controller is just appears. My animation on the second view controller is work, but timing is wrong. I'll explain: I have two UIView animation blocks with different timing, but after this glitch, two animation blocks performed with same duration and animation become very dull. I'm thinking about recording a video to demonstrate the problem.

I don't understand what is the root of the problem. Maybe somebody encounter the same behaviour and know the reason?

My question is: how can I debug such behaviour? I didn't show any lines of code yet, because I'm not sure where the problem can hide.

Comment: I had weird navigation behavior sometime, because I forgot to call the super methods. So, for example, in the viewDidAppear method, I forgot to call super.viewDidAppear(animated).

Comment: @JanDoornbos thanks for a clue mate, I'll check it.

Comment: @JanDoornbos this is doesn't help unfortunately, but I'll continue to dig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a problem in my code. It was a UIImageView property which image was set in background queue. I forgot to set its property in the main queue block.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
...
})
```

Silly mistake that ruins animation! I decided to leave this question and answer in case somebody encounter same behaviour.

## Edit

I found that I used MKMapSnapshotter for map creation which I put into dispatch async block since I don't want to block main queue for map image generation. Right now, I got, that I don't need to do it, since: `method executes the request asynchronously` and have completion handler which called in the main queue. I removed all dispatch related code and all fine now.